# Network Activity w/o Terminal

Tags: networking, monitor

While I can in *certain* cases appreciate the information floor provided by `nload`, et al. network monitors, how hard would it have been for Canon to just have the three-box network symbol on the top bar to **BLINK** when there actually IS activity?

My needs at this time only require one KNOWS there is activity; not so much of bytes, packets, etc. Is there any program available to provide this? the Ubuntu Software page does not list such, and my web searches have only shown what seem such outdated terminal-esk programs that they do not install or run on Ubuntu Fossa 20.04.

Comment: Investigate SNMP, the Simple Networking Management Protocol.

Comment: uumm, wait,... what?! I ask a question about the Ubuntu **User Interface**, and I am suggested interacting with a Network Management Protocol?

Comment: "How hard it would be for Canon"? It's a SMOP, but why? SMOP: Simple Matter Of Programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `indicator-multiload` (System Load Indicator) can be configured to only show a simple, horizontally-scrolling bar graph without numbers. The indicator displays on the top bar(dash).

**First**, install the package by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install indicator-multiload
```

**Next**, search for the application "System Load Indicator" and start the application.

**Now**, on the top bar, right-click on the indicator and select "preferences"

Under "monitored resources," make sure "Network" is the only one selected.

Adjust the width and the update interval to your preference. Personally, I like 40 pixels and 500 milliseconds.

For the color scheme, left-click on "download," "upload," or "localhost" to change the color of the graph. I like to use yellow for download and red for upload and blue for localhost.

If you do not want numbers to show on the top bar, place the mouse cursor on the graph and scroll up using your mouse wheel or your touchpad scroll function. Scroll down if you want to view the numbers on the top bar.

With these settings, the indicator will simply indicate when there is network traffic scrolling from right to left. A quick burst of traffic will display as a single line and longer intervals of network traffic will show as a solid bar.

Comment: YUMMY!!!! Yes! THIS! is what I was looking for! (kinda wondering why this is not On by default) I find that 125pix/100ms is useful for me, but THANK YOU mchid!! This is what I was l looking for!